# Can I create a MySQL column with a MULTISET datatype?

Tags: mysql

I would like to add a column in a MySQL table, where the column would accept a variable-length and unordered collection of elements aka [MULTISET](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp).

I tried: `ALTER TABLE Students ADD COLUMN Medical MULTISET;`

But MySQL isn't happy with an `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

I haven't seen any examples of a column created with a MULTISET datatype on the net, and I being to think I'm on the wrong track.

Answer (score 1):

No. [MySQL does *not* have a 'MULTISET' type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html). (And yes, this yet another reason why not to use that 'No. 1' search result site..)

While lots of designs use a "comma separated string"<sup>1</sup>, this is often a suitable case to utilize the proven Relational Algebra model.

That is, introduce a separate table/relation and the appropriate constraints.

---

<sup>1</sup> Using "comma separate strings" usually ends up being problematic as it lives outside the RA model, although it also has some built-in 'support' via FIND_IN_SET. Likewise the JSON data type can be useful in certain cases, *when* the data is entirely opaque. However, both of these approaches can fail miserably when wishing to perform joins and ensure referential integrity.

Answer (score 0):

You can not.
Mysql not support "Multiset"
But if you want do that, you just relation by abstract, dont you foriegn key, and set next id for next record!

Comment: Why not use foreign key?